# Validation of a XML with same Tag name for multiple children

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dataset

I want get multiple values under a Tag called Default value.Ex

```
<DefaultValue>One </DefaultValue>
<DefaultValue>two</DefaultValue>
<DefaultValue>three</DefaultValue>
```

I want validate all three values in a single validation. That means my string may contain any one of the values One,two ,Three,..it should validate if it contains any one

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ValidationList>
     <Validation>
         <FieldType>Auto Number</FieldType>
         <DataColumn>5</DataColumn>
         <ErrorMessage>Value cannot be null</ErrorMessage>
     </Validation>
     <Validation>
         <FieldType>Date Time</FieldType>
         <DataColumn>15</DataColumn>
         <ErrorMessage>Value cannot be null</ErrorMessage>
         <DefaultValues>kj</DefaultValues>
     </Validation>
</ValidationList>
```

My current code is:

```
GetFieldTypeRow = ds.Tables["Validation"].Select("FieldType='"  + xFieldTypeCell.Value2 + "'");

if (GetFieldTypeRow.Length == 1 )
{
     iFieldValueCol = Convert.ToInt32(GetFieldTypeRow[0 ["Default Values"].ToString());

     if(xFieldValueCell.Value2== "A")
     {
         DataRow ResRow = ResultDt.NewRow();
         ResRow["WorkSheetName"] = MySheet.Name.ToString();
         ResRow["DataFieldType"] = xFieldTypeCell.Value2;
         ResRow["AtRow"] = xFieldValueCell.Row.ToString();
         ResRow["ErrorMessage"] = "Finished";
         ResultDt.Rows.Add(ResRow);
      }
```

I have stored the XML data in a dataset and I am accessing the dataset each time by using the tag names of single row. My table consists four columns.

Datafield,Datacolumn,Error MEsasge,Default values.

I want check three values under Default value tag at once how can i do that?

Comment: Add a snippet of code to show what you are trying and elaborate the question.

Comment: Example data won't harm either

Comment: <Validation>
    <FieldType>Date Time</FieldType>
    <DataColumn>15</DataColumn>
    <ErrorMessage>Value cannot be null</ErrorMessage>
  <DefaultValues>kj</DefaultValues>
  </Validation>
 <Validation>
  <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
  <DataColumn>15</DataColumn>
  <ErrorMessage>Value cannot be null</ErrorMessage>
  <DefaultValues>P</DefaultValues>
 </Validation>

Comment: Florian Schmidinger ,<Default values>A|F|B</DefaultValues>..At a single attempt the validation result should be true if it contains A, F, B, any of this charecter.I am using Xml file tht XML file have the tag called Defaultvalues when i am reading the tag it showes error if i use tag <Default values>A|F|B</DefaultValues>.but if i use <Default values>A</DefaultValues>. single value it works fine .please help me out.

Comment: Add the snippet of code of your try and the example data ... Edit the question... not comment... harder to read

Comment: –  Florian Schmidinger thts my XML code.i want decalre more than one values in XML with same tag name.Example<Defaultvalues>A|F|R</Default values>

Comment: The c# code? what did you try? We all can't figure out what's this about... Ask yourself the question ... if i would read the question could I understand the problem?

Comment: Florian Schmidinge..atleast now could u understand what i meant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not completly satisfied with the question but let me give it a shot.

First let me point out that a default value is usually a **single value**. 
This value is usually set automatically when you add a new row or is set to the value when you don't assign a value to that field. So you rather need a column named `ValidValues`.

Now if you want to check for each value in this column:

```
string[] validValues = /*whereever you get the field from*/.Split('|');
bool valid = validValues.Contains(/*whatever value you want to check*/);
```

Comment: Florian Schmidinger y......i dnt knw how to split the values .Actually my XML file is preloaded.THe whole XML file is loaded and stored in Datatable.Am checking values every time in that table.The table now store a value under Default value coulum is [A].so if my string has value [A] than both fine.If my string has [B] it shows error because in datatble it has oly A.i want that table should have more than one value in its colum likeA,B,C so that if my string has any of this 3 values than it should work fine,

Comment: @nanthakumar The problem is that I still can't figure out from what you posted how your code is supposed to work. The code is not even compiling for me because it has serious errors like: iFieldValueCol = Convert.ToInt32(GetFieldTypeRow[0 ["Default Values"].ToString()); It's not very readable either... even with my edit. I'm trying to help you but you have to point exactly to your problem in order to get an exact answer. I'm a MCP but im no wizard and nor are other users of this forum.

Comment: Florian Schmidinger...i got it ...thank you ...as u recomended i just use split.method.thank you

Comment: @nanthakumar no need to say thank you but you are welcome. If my answer solved the issue you should consider accepting the answer though (little check symbol to the left of the answer). it gives us both a little reputation and the other users of the forum see that the issue is solved, so it benefits us all.

Comment: Florian Schmidinger ..sure i will do as u said.. am new to this forum completely.yet to learn things.